# Uppercase characters not allowed in functions config variable names

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

After executing this Firebase CLI command:
`firebase functions:config:set osp.google.clientId=...`

I get: `Error: Invalid config name osp.google.clientId, cannot use upper case`

Given that [Firebase environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?authuser=0) are based on Google Runtime Configuration (GRC), why aren't them allowed?

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.configs.variables?authuser=0#Variable) explains possible variable names in GRC, and it certainly allows uppercase characters.

Not that it affects me, but it isn't properly documented in Firebase's docs.

Comment: To report problems with the Firebase CLI, please file a bug report.  Don't post to Stack Overflow.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I don't think it's a bug, at least not on Firebase's platform, maybe on Firebase's documentation. Should I still create a bug report?

Comment: Yes, when the documentation is incorrect, and you can provide a reproduction case, it's a bug.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @RemeesMSyde https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?authuser=0#set_environment_configuration_with_the
>  Keep in mind that only lowercase characters are accepted in keys; uppercase characters are not allowed.